# Spring Data Neo4j Cypher get entity type or class name

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my SDN 4 project I have a following Cypher query(a part of query):

```
(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)
```

for example I can get `id` of entity with a following Cypher function `id(entity)`

How to get entity name or class name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `labels` function

`match (entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup) return id(entity), labels(entity)`

For each row returned, you'll get the Neo4j id and array of labels.

Assuming your NodeEntity class labels match at least one of these labels, you can then iterate and load the appropriate class instance yourself.

Generally speaking you shouldn't need to do this however.

If (entity) is polymorphic, SDN/OGM will hydrate the correct objects for you. It pretty much does under the hood what I described above, but it also handles matching on interfaces, subclasses, etc.

Comment: Thanks, labels works ! SDN/OGM magic doesn't work right now in case of projection for @QueryResult objects with Session.query.. this is why I still need to do this manually